# .net expando object and LINQ. Possible or not?

Tags: .net, linq, expandoobject

I have a simple list of expando objects called products.

i add various fields to these objects at runtime ( for example color or size)

How can i write a LINQ query on this list based on dynamic fields ?

With a classic list of objects i could write a LINQ query like this :

```
From item in Products Where item.color="red" select item
```

but with expandos , how this can be achieved , knowing that i don't know in advance the name of the fields (it could be size of weight or anything else ) ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expando object implements IDictionary(Of String, Object)
Thus you could cast it to an IDictionary and access it's properties by passing a string.

Comment: Brilliant ! i was turning around for Hours and it works : from item as IDictionary(of String,Object) in products Where item("color")="Red" .... Thank You Sir !

Answer (score 0):

You can write your code like this:
From item in Products Where (item as dynamic).color="red" select item